# build.gradle error: Could not create tastk ':generateLockfiles'. in Flutter project but App is running normal

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, build.gradle

I have an error in my build.gradle file (android/build.gradle) in my Flutter project. The App is running completely normal but this error is still not looking good to me.
Does anyone ever had this problem/error?

[image]

[image]

Here is my complete build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

flutter doctor -v Output:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.0.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22598.200], locale de-DE)
    • Flutter version 3.0.5 at C:\Flutter\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision f1875d570e (5 weeks ago), 2022-07-13 11:24:16 -0700
    • Engine revision e85ea0e79c
    • Dart version 2.17.6
    • DevTools version 2.12.2

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\jjkla\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-31, build-tools 30.0.3
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)

[√] VS Code (version 1.70.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\jjkla\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.46.0

[√] Connected device (2 available)
    • Chrome (web) • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 104.0.5112.81
    • Edge (web)   • edge   • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 104.0.1293.54

[√] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

• No issues found!
```

**EDIT 1:** Since this happened to me over a year ago now, I don't remember exactly what solved the error. But there was definitely an incompatible version with conflicted with another version. General Advice: You should take a look at your Kolin Version in `android/build.gradle` under `ext.kotlin_version = 'x.x.x'`. Take a look at the  to find the [**Kotlin Website**](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#release-details) newest available Kolin Version.

Comment: Can you run the flutter doctor -v and share the output?

Comment: @NewDeveloper I added the output.

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77456841/7389293

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Same problem here, but in **Linux and Visual Studio code**.

With `./gradlew` in android directory, the build failed due wrong Java version. Was Java 1.8, but must be at least 11. After update my java version, `./gradlew` built successfully.

After **restart** visual studio code, the error was gone.

Comment: So what did you do? Did you update Java? How? Where?

Comment: I just updated the java version.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to open Android directory (which is in my flutter project) with Android studio, Android studio suggested to upgrade and then I followed suggestion, and finally error is solved now.

Answer (score 1):

You can do flutter clean and flutter pub get and then try to build again.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to rebuild the `build.gradle` file.
Just follow these steps.

```
cd android 
./gradlew clean  
./gradlew build
```

You can also execute this command in one line.

```
./gradlew clean build
```

Answer (score 0):

open your android project in android studio
file > open > in your flutter project choose android file
then rebuild gradle, I have same problem and solved it like this.

Comment: how do I rebuild in Android Studio? is there a button for this?

Answer (score 0):

This error can be occurred if you change the name of your app under `pubspec.yaml` file

[image]

you can resolve this error by two ways

1. reverting the previous name
2. Going under projects `build.gradle` file and change this

   ```
    subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
    }
   ```

to

```
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/Groic"
}
```

we've changed `project.name` with the name mentioned in `pubspec.yaml`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to install java 11 version or higher.
Download java 11 version install it on your system > restart vs code or whichever code editor you are using > in terminal you can run flutter clean and then run flutter pub get

Make the following changes to your build.gradle file:
[image: Recommended change #1 in build.gradle file]
[image: Recommended change #2 in build.gradle file]

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35444018)

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem is version mismatch ( java and gradle )

In my flutter project i faced the same problem, now i fix it.

Here is how?

First check your Java version run by this command `javac --version`

In my case my java version is **21** and then go to the Gradle's site now you can see the correct version that matches your java version

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html

Then go to your flutter project directory, and then go to > android > gradle > gradle-wrapper.properties

In this file you can see distributionUrl like this

> distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.4-all.zip

Then change the correct version that matches your java version.
for example instead of **gradle-8.4-all.zip** you can change you varsion and save the file and then reload window run `flutter pub get`

This will solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

For me it was definitely related to the java version, installing java 11 and giving the correct JAVA_HOME path in Environment Variables and restarting the computer eliminated the problem

Answer (score 0):

**These are the step I handle above error.**

first check errors in flutter:

```
flutter doctor
```

then rebuld build.gradle:

```
cd android 
./gradlew clean  
./gradlew build
./gradlew clean build
```

*Optional tasks:*

```
flutter upgrade
flutter pub get
```

then **restart** the IDE and check.