# Error while opening VS code with Flutter project

Tags: flutter

Whenever I open VS code with a Flutter project I always get the following error message:

```
The supplied phased action failed with an exception.
Could not create task ':generateLockfiles'.
Process 'command 'C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\flutter\flutter_application_4\android/gradlew.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

This error comes every time I try to open VS code with a Flutter project

Comment: Checkout this link it might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73357365/build-gradle-error-could-not-create-tastk-generatelockfiles-in-flutter-proj

Comment: Almost all of those i have tried. Still I am not getting the error resolved.

Comment: Hey the error got resolved. I did check the versions and did make the versions check as per the gradle matrix https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html